# Dynamically inject compiled applications in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, webpack, frontend

I have a requirement to develop multiple Angular 2 applications independently by various teams. Each team will have independent releases scheduled. Towards the end, all these applications will need to be injected into one main application at runtime. They will need to work as a Single Page Application.
We tried Lazy loading modules of Angular 2. One of the roadblocks we see is that we cannot compile the main application using web pack without having the lazy load modules in the project solution.

Here is the structure of my present solution:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt0PH.png)

This is how I defined the routes

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbpXS.png)

We have defined two routes that lazy loads two modules(LazyModule and MoreLazyModule). This solution works fine.
When we remove those modules from the solution try to build it using web pack, the compiler throws an error.
Is there any way we can decouple the modules to develop them as independent projects and inject those modules in production?

Comment: instead creating module in same application, you can create those components as a separate libraries and then import them in your project.

Comment: hi.. did you managed to develop and deploy independently??

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading is the solution for your problem (at least as far as I know).

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to build is an app which has an external container (app.module and app.component) which need to orchestrate several other independent apps. The whole thing needs to behave as a Single Page Application.

If this is the case, then what I suggest you to do is the following:

- have a team (or an individual responsible for all the code of the
  Container app (app.module, app.component, any other common code you
  may want to share among the various apps) - the Container app
  references all the subApps (and gets updates as soon as a new subApp
  is added)
- have different teams responsible for the different subApps - these
  teams work on the code of their competence, submit to the code
  repository when ready, but use the entire project (i.e. also the
  subApps of the other teams) any time they build

I do not see any issue in organizing the work like this, as soon as every team checks in the code to the central code repository only when all tests have passed (and the tests cover the application functionalities thoroughly). The coordination effort required to the team responsible for the Container app is really minimal.

Comment: We want each application to be independently developed,tested and deployed with their own version numbers. I mean to say that the teams and repositories will also be different.

We achieved this functionality with AngularJS and RequireJS. With new Angular framework and webpack, we are facing issues to dynamically inject modules into the applicaiton

Comment: Then one way to develop each subApp as an independent library which is imported by the main Container app as any other external library (as Rachit Solanki has already suggested). Depending on the specific context, testing each subApp autonomously may be a challenge (e.g. what if you have a central login). But, if you have already done this, it means you know how to solve it